# Multiprocessing or Multithreading for scraping using API calls?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to scrape a website with API calls using python. Since the number of requests to be made is high in number I was thinking to use multithreading or multiprocessing for the task. I got confused on which would be a better fit for the task. Kindly you share your knowledge on this!

Comment: Multithreading since what you are doing is largely I/O bound and there is far less overhead in creating threads compared with processes.

Comment: Multithreading - for IO-bound tasks. Multiprocessing - for CPU-bound tasks. Page loads to long? - Threads. Page parsing is too long? - Processes.

Comment: +1 for both comments. Depending on how tight your deadlines are, it might be interesting for you to look at the `concurrent.futures` package, and run controlled experiments with `ThreadPoolExecutor` vs `ProcessPoolExecutor`

Comment: maybe you should see framework [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which already use `Pool` (and other ideas) and you don't have to care of this.

Comment: there are modyfications of module `requests` which already use `threading`, `multiprocessing` or `asyncio` - ie. [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) uses `asyncio`